# TypeScript 'Record' is not defined

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code

I am writing a React-Native project with TypeScript, so far everything works fine but the following part throws an error:

```
export interface Country {
    name: string;
    cities: Record<string, string>;
}
```

The error is:

```
3:13  error  'Record' is not defined  no-undef
```

My typescript uses the workspace version instead of VS Code's version.
Also, when I cmd+click on the `Record`, I can go to its definition, which is in the file `lib.es5.d.ts`:

```
type Record<K extends keyof any, T> = {
    [P in K]: T;
};
```

So, `Record` is obviously defined and found under node_modules, however when I run the linter (@typescript-eslint), I can't fix this error

The content of my `.vscode/settings.json` looks like following:

```
"typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib"
```

I have not found any solutions, could you help please?

Typescript version: "4.1.4",

Comment: it might be missing the es5 (or compatible) lib in the compiler flags (tsconfig.json compilierOptions => lib)

Answer (score 4):

This error might be related to the `eslint` configuration.

make eslint extend `'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended'` by adding it to `extends` section of `eslintrc` file:

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    extends: [
        ...
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended'
    ]
    ....
};
```

and reload vscode's TypeScript Server. you can do so by typing `Restart TS Server` in vscode command palette.